# Puppeteer - ProtocolError: Protocol error (Page.printToPDF): Printing is not available

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I get the below error when trying to print PDF with Puppetter. I've not been able to find much information about this error online. Does this mean this particular page just doesn't support PDF or is there a setting in my code that could ammend this? Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

```
export const create = async (dev: boolean = true) => {
        
        const username = process.env.USERNAME;
        const password = process.env.PASSWORD;
    
        const options = dev
            ? {
                    headless: false,
                    slowMo: 25, 
              }
            : {};
    
        const browser = await Puppeteer.launch(options);
        const page = await browser.newPage();
    
        await page.goto(LOGIN_URL, {
            waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        });
    
        await page.type(USERNAME_INPUT_ID, username);
        
        const passwordInputHandle = await page.$(PASSWORD_INPUT_ID);
        await passwordInputHandle.type(password);
        await passwordInputHandle.press("Enter");
    
        await page.pdf({ path: path.join(TEMP_FOLDER, "hn.pdf"), format: "a4" });
    
        await browser.close();
    };
```

Answer (score 24):

PDF creation is **only** supported in `headless` mode.

So this should work:

```
const browser = await Puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
```